# Capybara - how ignore form action url after for click_button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, coffeescript, capybara

I have following form for creating payment:

**payments/_form.htmlerb**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">

    <%= form_tag  class: "form-horizontal", id: "payment-form" do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "CardRegistrationURL", card_reg['CardRegistrationURL'], id: "CardRegistrationURL" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "PreregistrationData", card_reg['PreregistrationData'], id: "PreregistrationData" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "AccessKey", card_reg['AccessKey'], id: "AccessKey" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "CardId", card_reg['Id'] %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'project_url', contract_path(@contract), id: "contractUrlHidden" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'finialize_url', finialize_url, id: "finializeUrl" %>



      <fieldset>
        <div id="legend">
          <legend class="">Deposit for contract <%= @contract.title %></legend>
        </div>

        <div id="legend">
          <legend class="">Amount <%= @contract.amount %></legend>
        </div>

        <!-- Name -->
        <div class="control-group">
          <%= label "card_holder", "Card Holder's Name", class:"control-label" %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= text_field_tag "card_holder", '', { id: "username", class: "input-xlarge"} %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Card Number -->
        <div class="control-group">
          <%= label "card_number", "Card number", class:"control-label" %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= text_field_tag "Alias", '', { id: "card_number", class: "input-xlarge"} %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Expiry-->
        <div class="control-group">
          <%= label "expity_date", "Card Expiry Date", '', class:"control-label" %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= text_field_tag "ExpirationDate", '', { id: "card_expiration_date", class: "input-xlarge"} %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- CVV -->
        <div class="control-group">
          <%= label "cvv", "Card CVV", class:"control-label" %>
          <div class="controls">
            <%= text_field_tag "cardCvx", '', { id: "cardCvx", class: "input-xlarge"} %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Save card -->
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox" for="save_card">
              <%= label "save_card", class:"check_box" %>
              <input type="checkbox"> <!-- , '', id="save_card" value="option1"> //-->
              Save card on file?
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Submit -->
        <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <%= submit_tag "Pay now", {class: "btn btn-success", id: "process"} %>
          </div>
        </div>

      </fieldset>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**register_card.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#payment-form').submit (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()  
    $this = $(this)

    mangoPay.cardRegistration.init
      cardRegistrationURL: $("#CardRegistrationURL").val()
      preregistrationData: $("#PreregistrationData").val()
      accessKey: $("#AccessKey").val()

    cardData = {
      cardNumber: $("#card_number").val()
      cardExpirationDate: $("#card_expiration_date").val()
      cardCvx: $("#cardCvx").val()
    }
    contract_url =  $("#contractUrlHidden").val()
    finialize_url = $("#finializeUrl").val()
    mangoPay.cardRegistration.sendDataWithAjax(
      # URL to capture response
      finialize_url,
      # Card data
      cardData,
      # Result Ajax callback
      (data) ->
        $this.replaceWith('<p> Payment okay</p> </br> <div id="contract_url"><a href="">Return back to project</a></div>')
        $("#contract_url a").attr("href", contract_url)

        #doRedirect = -> window.location.href = data['url']
        #setTimeout doRedirect, 2000

      (xhr, status, error) -> 
        alert("Payment error : " + xhr.responseText + " (" + status + " - " + error + ")")

    )

    return false
```

After click button "Pay now" will start script register_card.coffee. After success register card on view payments/new will render new text: Thank for payment. How test this correct?

I do following:

```
expect(current_path).to eq(new_payment_path)
    expect(page).to have_text("Deposit for contract")
    fill_in "card_holder", with: "firstname lastname"
    fill_in "Alias", with: "4706750000000033"
    fill_in "ExpirationDate", with: "1017"
    click_button "Pay now"
    expect(current_path).to eq(new_payment_path)
    expect(page).to have_text("Return back to project")
```

But display error on line click_button "Pay now". 
**Failure/Error: click_button "Pay now"
ActionController::RoutingError:
No route matches [POST] "/payments/new"**

How me ignore [POST] "/payments/new? Becose all data send with ajax in script register_card.coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test POST requests with capybara. Basically, capybara is used to test user interaction, so if you manually take the steps described in the test form, you should be able create the scenario you want. You should not check if the path is [POST]new_payment_path, but instead check if the path is redirected to the GET page (I believe it will be the index or the show action).
Furthermore, if it is done by ajax, you should use the js: true argument in the scenario clause; however, for this you will need a javascript driver (I succesfully used [Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) for this kind of scenarios).

Comment: thank you. but how test in my situation? I need test, that after click "pay now" will render new content on page payments/new with text for example Thank you for you payment.

Comment: Let's have a little insight first. The user clicks the Pay now button which goes to a POST action. You should not check if the path is POST first of all. If you redirect the user with a flash, just check for the flash message. If you could share some sample code I could help you with this.